# Custom bash tab completion

Tags: bash

I have my custom console utility `cooltool` with list of options

```
fooOption
barOption
```

What should I do to able bash autocomplete the options by pressing the `tab` key?

I mean the user typed

```
$ ./cooltool foo_
```

then pressed `tab`. And then

```
$ ./cooltool fooOption _
```

appeared.

Comment: Don't cross post.

Comment: Notice that this one is migrated and the other isn't. I think a lot of users still don't realize that they shouldn't be posting a question on multiple SE sites. They're used to disparate forums that aren't a unified system, where you might ask in a few different forums for a better chance of a fast answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a bash completion script for `cooltool`. The [bash-completion](http://www.caliban.org/bash/#completion) package comes with scripts for many popular programs, which you can use as examples.

Answer (score 51):

The simplest way is to add the following to your .bashrc.

```
_cooltool()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "fooOption barOption" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _cooltool cooltool
```

Whenever you type `cooltool f[TAB][TAB]`, the `_cooltool()` function is invoked. It will work out what your current partial word is and then `compgen` will work out which options match. These are stored in an array called `COMPREPLY` which is then displayed. Look at `man complete` and `man compgen` for details.

For a nice tutorial check out: [Writing your own Bash Completion Function](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html)

Answer (score 8):

You might want to take a closer look inside your /etc/bash_completion.d directory on your system.

Also you should read [this introduction](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1). The [second part of the introduction](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) is the one you need.

Comment: I am using the Mac OS X 10.6, so there is no /etc/bash_completion.d directory

Comment: Ah Ok, good to know.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the code that is used for git bash completion](https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)

Comment: interesting to read :)

Comment: Please include at least a summary of the answer in your answer, not just a link. See the site FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to dogbane's answer, you could also do:

```
complete -W "fooOption barOption" cooltool
```

if you simply want to match a list of words from the beginning of the string.  It seems that complete and compgen share most options.  I've only noticed "beginning of string" matching in the commands I use, so I found it neat that you can do other things in the _cooltool function like:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(grep "$cur" ~/my_potential_args.txt) )
```

to match anywhere in the option name.